# How to Grep and Replace With Exclusions

Tags: bash, sed, grep

How can I replace some strings in some files recursively, taking some exclusions into account? For example, I don't want to apply the replacement to binary files or files in .svn directories.

Comment: For everything but the binary part, you can use `find . -not -name "*.svn" -exec sed -i 's/foobar/baz/g' {} \;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I'm currently using, perhaps there is a better way?

```
grep -irl foobar | grep -v .svn | grep -v Binary | xargs sed -i 's/foobar/baz/g'
```